# How to add a texts daily to an exist flutter app Via Firebase?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-storage

I have created a simple flutter app Consists of one page .. this one page contains questions and answers below .. this app was uploaded on Google Play and i want to add new questions and answers daily manually Via any database .. For example Firebase .. how can i do this?

Comment: Share some code. Are you already using any databases? If not, just use the Firebase examples and you can get to your desired target pretty quickly.

This question is to broad to answer.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.